# Blob in NextJs for images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I need to add image url as a blob using technologies like next and node as a backend.

First I try use simple way to create what I need.

```
const ErrorMsg = (props) => {
    const image = "/logo.png";
    const blob = new Blob([image], {type: 'image/png'})
    const img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.errorMsg}>
                <img src={img} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

First time I don't know how but it works like in [**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-shtern-dk54m)   image not showing but also webpack not give an error.

I forget how I it breaked but I got this error after I use  some code manipulations trying to fix it.

`Blob is not defined`.

I thought need an extra package so I install `node-blob`

```
import Blob from "node-blob";

const ErrorMsg = (props) => {
    const image = "/logo.png";
    const blob = new Blob([image], {type: 'image/png'})
    const img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.errorMsg}>
                <img src={img} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

So now I getting this error `URL.createObjectURL is not a function`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) is part of the Web API, thus not available on the server side of your app.

If you need to use both of them, you should use them inside a `useEffect`, which will only be triggered client side.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ErrorMsg = (props) => {
    const image = "/logo.png";
    const [src, setSrc] = useState(''); // initial src will be empty

    useEffect(() => {
      const blob = new Blob([image], {type: 'image/png'})
      const img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      setSrc(img); // after component is mount, src will change
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.errorMsg}>
                <img src={src} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

That said, is there a reason you need to create a Blob? You can serve static files for Next.js by storing them under a folder named `public`, as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Comment: Ty for answer error message gone but  still image is not displaying. I create image as Blob because I dont want anyone parse images from my website.

Comment: I have never used `Blob` for this reason and I'm not sure if you can combine `Blob` and `createObjectURL` like above.

Comment: Also, even if you manage to do something like this, you will again end up with an `src` that can be parsed, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-driscoll-ffho3) example I've created.

Comment: I combine `Blob` and `createObjectURL` like above but as I say this didn't work.Also why you use blob in your website?

Answer (score 2):

If You want to use the `next/image` component with blob files, you can set the `unoptimized` property on the component, Blob URLs reside in memory, so it's temporary and doesn't need to be optimized.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized

Answer (score 1):

the better way is that you import your component with dynamic import :

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const MyComponentNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('./MyComponentNoSSR'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```